# Why does it add the text at the beginning of next line, and not the end of the right one?

Tags: php, regex, flat-file

**Needed solution:**

I am working with a simple PHP script that should:

1. Add "value4:::" at the end of the first line in a file
2. Add ":::" at the end of all the next lines

I am novise in programming, and have sit here for two days trying to figure this out. Might be a little detail, or it might be totally wrong way of doing this task.

It might be wrong way to do this, or may be a regex problem? I really don't know.

I kindly ask you to help me with the solution.

---

**Information:**

The file **newstest.db** looks like this:

```
ID:::value1:::value2:::value3:::
1:::My:::first:::line:::
2:::My:::second:::line:::
3:::Your:::third:::line:::
```

And using this php script I'd like to make it look like this:

```
ID:::value1:::value2:::value3:::value4:::
1:::My:::first:::line::::::
2:::My:::second:::line::::::
3:::Your:::third:::line::::::
```

---

**Problem:**

So far I have almost got it, but I am confused to why it adds the "value4:::" to the *beginning* of the *second* line, and then add ":::" at the beginning (not end) of all of the rest of the lines.

So I get a file that looks like this:

```
ID:::value1:::value2:::value3:::
value4:::1:::My:::first:::line:::
:::2:::My:::second:::line:::
:::3:::Your:::third:::line:::
```

I thought that:

```
$lineshere = 'Some text here:::';    
$lines1 = $linehere.'value4:::';
```

would output "Some text here:::value4:::"

May be the problem is due to this way of adding line after line?

```
$lines = '';
$lines.= 'My test';
$lines.= ' is here';
echo $lines;
```

I am a novise in programming, so I might have used totally wrong functions tec to make this work.

But in this case it seams to add a space or line break/ line end in the wrong place.

---

**My try on this solution:**

```
<?php
// specify the file
$file_source="newstest.db";

// get the content of the file
$newscontent = file($file_source, true);

//set a start value (clear memory)
$lines ='';

// get each line and treat it line by line. 

foreach ($newscontent as $line_num => $linehere) {  

    // add "value4:::" at the end of FIRST line only, and put it in memory $lines 
    if($line_num==0) {
        $lines.= $linehere.'value4:::';

        // Just to see what the line looks like
        //echo 'First line: '.$lines.'<br /><br />';
    }

    // then add ":::" to the other lines and add them to memory $lines
    if($line_num>0) {
        $lines1 = $linehere.':::';
        $lines.= $lines1;

        //just look at the line
        //echo 'Line #'.$line_num.': '.$lines1.'<br /><br />';
    }
}

//Write new content to $file_source
$f = fopen($file_source, 'w');
fwrite($f,$lines);
fclose($f);

echo "// to show the results ar array<br /><br />";

$newscontentlook = file($file_source, true);
print_r(array_values($newscontentlook));
?>
```

Comment: Just as a side note: you may want to look at your files using a hex editor to see the newline/ carriage return characters as well.

Comment: I believe, this is due to the fact that $linehere ends with a linebreak.

Comment: What is the purpose of `true` in the line `$newscontent = file($file_source, true);`? Change it to `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` and it should work.

Comment: this is very easy to achieve with `file_get_contents` and `preg_replace`, I've posted an answer below

Comment: Thank you all so much. I am looking through all solutions suggested now :-)

Comment: @ClasG : When using `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` the flat file is saved with everything one one line. I need one line per ID.  Please correct me if I added it wrong. I wrote `$newscontent = file($file_source, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);`

Comment: I'm (very) far from a php-expert, but reading the documentation it states `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES - Do not add newline at the end of each array element`. [Check it here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually very easy to achieve with [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), i.e:

```
$content = file_get_contents("newstest.db");
$content = preg_replace('/(^ID:.*\S)/im', '$1value4:::', $content);
$content = preg_replace('/(^\d+.*\S)/im', '$1:::', $content);
file_put_contents("newstest.db", $content);
```

---

Output:

```
ID:::value1:::value2:::value3:::value4:::
1:::My:::first:::line::::::
2:::My:::second:::line::::::
3:::Your:::third:::line::::::
```

---

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/FTfHy0)

Comment: This was a clever approach. I have one problem though. It now adds "value4:::" as a new line below the first line etc. The same for each new ":::". Any idea why? Is it related to the way I get the contents of the file?

Comment: try adding `\S` at the end of both regexes, I've updated answer. `\S` Match a single character that is NOT a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line) «\S»

Comment: I'm sorry. I am really noob when it comes to regex. I didn't understand where to put `\S` . I tried after the `im` but that didn't work. How should it look?

Comment: Just see me answer, it's there

Comment: Oh. I looked in the answer above. I now see it in the link to deone.com

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Am now just testing with different values to see that it always works :-)

Answer (score 2):

the function `file()` gives you the file in an array with each line being an element of the array. Each ending of the line (`EOL`) is included in the elements. So appending text to that line will be after the `EOL`, and thus effectively on the beginning of the next line.

You can either choose to not use `file()` and explode the text yourself on the `EOL`, so the `EOL` is no longer part of the array element. Then edit the elements, and implode the array again.

Or `fopen()` the file, and `fread()` through it yourself. The latter option is preferred, as it won't load the entire file into memory at once.

Comment: Good explanation. Could be solved with the current approach though, by adding the flag `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` (if I'm not totally wrong).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your loop through the lines read by file() function:

```
foreach ($newscontent as $line_num => $linehere) {
  ...
```

`$linehere` contains a newline at the end, so you should simply chop it before using it:

```
foreach ($newscontent as $line_num => $linehere) {
  $linehere = chop($linehere);
  ...
```

If you don't `chop` the line contents, when you concatenate a string to it, you'll get:

```
LINE_CONTENTS\nSTRING_ADDED
```

which, when printed, will be:

```
LINE_CONTENTS
STRING_ADDED
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This solved the space problem :-) However now everything is saved in ONE line when wrote back to the file. So I probably need to add a code that tells it to save each line with a "end of line"? Do you know how?

Comment: Yes: you can use `fputs()` instead of `fwrite()` when writing each line, or add a `\n` character at the end of each line before `fwrite()`...